# How can I reload an iframe inside iframe with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a domain,

```
example.com
```

Iframe's source is,

```
server1.example1.com
```

The problem is, I would like to refresh the iframe with JavaScript inside my iframe, when I `location.reload()` the page, Iframe loads empty and this only happens in chrome, How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible. I believe it is a violation of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)...

Comment: @War10ck but I don't violate anything, I just want to refresh my iframe, with javascript

Comment: Cross site scripting is a violation. ***server1.example1.com*** is treated as a separate domain.

Comment: @War10ck its my impression of his problem that he wants the script to run on `server1.example.com` (inside the iFrame itself, reloading itself). So no X-Site issues at all here. Just a weird browser-specific issue perhaps. @user.. could you maybe provide a jsfiddle or other minimal test case for us to tinker with?

Comment: I changed the way script work now, it is more complicated but, it works, thank you all for your help

Comment: @user3067113 perhaps you can add an answer with your code? (For the benefit of future users). Its not taboo to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try this:

```
// Reload the current page, without using the cache
document.location.reload(true);
```

*source*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

I know Chrome does some pretty clever things with its cache, so maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

right click and reload frame, seriousle:

If the iframe was not on a different domain, you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

But since the iframe is on a different domain, you will be denied access to the iframe's contentDocument property by the same-origin policy.

But you can hackishly force the cross-domain iframe to reload if your code is running on the iframe's parent page, by setting it's src attribute to itself. Like this:

```
// hackishly force iframe to reload
var iframe = document.getElementById(FrameId);
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

If you are trying to reload the iframe from another iframe, you are out of luck, that is not possible.

Comment: I want to reload my iframe with javascript, inside the same iframe

Comment: @user3067113 this clarification is still somewhat confusing. Let me see if I have this right. You only have 1 iframe. You want javaScript inside that iframe, to make that same iframe reload?

Comment: @ZachL I think it is reasonable :)