# iFrame Auto Refresh Doesn't Work on Chrome but works on IE

Tags: javascript, html

So I've got my iframe and code below.

It works in IE
Does not work on Chrome

I feel like I'm missing the smallest detail but I can't seem to get it working on Chrome.

```
<body>
<iframe id="idcw" name="cw" src="/cw.htm" scrolling="No" frameBorder="0" style="border:none; width:100%; height:1300px;"></iframe>

<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 10000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["cw"].location.reload();
 document.getElelementById("idcw").location.reload();
}

</script>
</body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

ps I've also tried the following which didn't work

```
document.getElelementById('idcw').location.reload();
document.getElelementById['idcw'].location.reload();
document.getElelementById["idcw"].location.reload();
document.getElelementById("idcw").location.reload();
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382966/how-can-i-reload-an-iframe-inside-iframe-with-javascript . This action violates same-origin policy, so it's blocked. The Developer Console should have a notice for that.

Comment: It didn't but I figured it out; (below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following placed at the bottom of my body tag (in case anyone needed this);

```
<script>

window.setInterval("reloadIFrame1();", 60000);

function reloadIFrame1() {
 document.frames["idcw"].location.reload();
}

window.setInterval("reloadIFrame2();", 60000);

function reloadIFrame2() {
 document.getElementById('idcw').src = document.getElementById('idcw').src; 
}

</script>
```